# Use IP address in Redirect URIs instead of domain in google api?

Tags: php, google-api, ip, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Can I use ip address instead of domain address in Redirect URIs in Google API console.

I have a code for getting access from Google API , it works good for domain address . when user has some IP address instead of domain address it says

```
OAuth 2 redirect URL "http://11.100.251.13/googleAnalytics/lib/googleAnalytics.php" is invalid.
```

Comment: looks like the answer is no